# Error in duplicate record in Access 2010

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I should work with a database into the Access 2010 recently. It has few Tables, a few Queries based on their tables and finally a Form. The Form has a button for duplication records. When I click the button then I get this error message:  "**some of the field names you tried to paste don't match field names on the form**" ... after passing of this message, some of fields have been duplicated (only a few fields) and most of all records have not been duplicated and they are invisible in the Form. I changed the fields name into the related table but the issue still remained.
Do you have any idea for solving this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "some of the field names you tried to paste don't match field names on the form" this sounds like a keystroke macro or some Really Bad Idea instead of a proper implementation.